# Why Deployment of ERC20 token contract to Ropsten is taking lot of time?

Tags: contract-deployment, ropsten, bug

I'm trying to deploy my ERC20 token contract on Ropsten network, It took 2hr 30 mins and still pending, what is happening, any problem with deployments? 
Is it linked to the recent **batchOverflow Bug in Multiple ERC20 Smart Contracts (CVE-2018–10299)** Look [here](https://medium.com/@peckshield/alert-new-batchoverflow-bug-in-multiple-erc20-smart-contracts-cve-2018-10299-511067db6536)

I have to deploy my ICO today, if some one have any news please let me know.
Thanks,
Fariha

Comment: Could you give the tx hash?

Comment: I redployed: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xddeb64f7a45a9d6d86f077b3f8a540ec38338c548102bc2f47e3a323952a3f56

Comment: Even small contracts are also time consuming.

Comment: That hash is not working (even the link you provided). Anyway, maybe people are just not mining in the network?

Comment: The transaction has not yet into mempool of etherscan. Quite surprising that it has been 6 hours. What noode you synced? Could u provide the tx hash (not link)? Maybe a case, when tx reached mempool of etherscan but due to low gas price no miners mine it and other txs replace this from pool.

Comment: I set the gas price to 330 and it worked then, previously it was 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no relation with the batchOverflow bug, it also happen with mist wallet.it could be due to no miner available. i recommends remix with meta masks.the best way maximum developer prefer

Answer (score 1):

Since your transaction isn't showing on Etherscan, the tx must either have 0 gas price (dropped by nodes) or not making it to the network at all. What are you deploying from? Metamask, Truffle, something else?